# Pass a C++ object from a C++ application to python script into the constructor of another C++ object

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ library with 2 classes defined in it: **t_foo** and **t_bar**. I need a object of t_foo to be able to create a object of t_bar. I use boost.python to generate a wrapper for this library and for this classes.

I import this library in a python script. I create a object bar of the class t_bar in a function **test_function** in this python script. The object foo, that is needed to create bar, is NOT created in the python script, but has to be passed into the function as a parameter.

Now i import this python script in a C++ application. I create a object foo of the class t_foo and pass it into the function test_function as a parameter. On executing of this function i get this error:

> Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>     t_bar.**init**(t_bar, t_foo) did not match C++ signature:
>     **init**(struct _object*, class t_foo)

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I am using Visual Studio 2013, Python 3.4 and Boost 1.56.0.

This is code from the C++ library:

-- file t_foo.h --

```
#include <iostream>

class t_foo
{
public:
    t_foo(){};
};

class t_bar
{
public:
    t_bar( const t_foo& p_foo ):
        m_foo( p_foo )
    {};

private:
    const t_foo& m_foo;
};

#include "t_foo.h"

#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

-- file t_foo.cpp --

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( ex_two_lib )
{
    boost::python::class_< t_foo, boost::noncopyable >( "t_foo" );
    boost::python::class_< t_bar, boost::noncopyable >( "t_bar", boost::python::init< const t_foo& >() );
}
```

This is the python script:

```
import ex_two_lib

def test_function( p_foo ):
    bar = ex_two_lib.t_bar( p_foo )

# the script itself
print( "no function call here. it will be called from c++." )
```

This is the c++ application:

```
#include <t_foo.h>

#include <cassert>

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>




void
init_module_ex_two_lib
(
    void
);


boost::python::object
import_python_object( const std::string& p_name, const std::string& p_path, boost::python::api::object& p_global )
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    try
    {
        dict locals;
        locals[ "modulename" ] = p_name;
        locals[ "path" ] = p_path;
        exec
        (
            "import imp\n"
            "newmodule = imp.load_module( modulename, open( path ), path,( 'py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE ) )\n",
            p_global,
            locals 
        );
        return locals[ "newmodule" ];
    }
    catch( boost::python::error_already_set const & )
    {
        if( PyErr_ExceptionMatches( PyExc_ZeroDivisionError ) )
        {
            assert( false );
        }
        else
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
    }
}




int
main
(
void
)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    init_module_ex_two_lib();

    try
    {
        boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import( "__main__" );
        boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr( "__dict__" );

        {
            boost::python::object script = import_python_object
            (
                "ex_one_script",
                "ex_two_script.py",
                main_namespace
            );

            boost::python::object test_function = script.attr( "test_function" );

            t_foo foo;
            boost::python::object function_result = test_function( boost::ref( foo ) );
        }
    }
    catch( boost::python::error_already_set const & )
    {
        if( PyErr_ExceptionMatches( PyExc_ZeroDivisionError ) )
        {
            assert( false );
        }
        else
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
    }
}
```